# Is there a difference between BundleId and AppID methods when reading the version of my app in the App Store?

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm testing how to read versions of my app in the App Store.

The problem with this feature is that it takes a long time to reflect the version of the latest released app.

In the initial test, the version was queried using BundleId.

However, I found out that the latest version viewable time is different depending on HTTP and HTTPS.

(I'm not saying who's faster. I think it's different from situation to situation that's reflected quickly.)

And I looked up using AppID.

Even when the latest version is queried only with HTTPS using BundleID, AppID queried the latest version regardless of HTTP and HTTPS.

But if you look at Stackoverflow, most of them use BundleID. Why is that??

I think it's fast to use AppID if my experiment is right, please let me know if I'm wrong.

Or

Bundle ID

- https://itunes.apple.com/kr/lookup?bundleId=com.test.testApp
- http://itunes.apple.com/kr/lookup?bundleId=com.test.testApp

App ID

- https://itunes.apple.com/kr/lookup?id=123456789
- http://itunes.apple.com/kr/lookup?id=123456789

All four situations above are applied at random, but were they just instantaneous situations?